# Iptables States

Tags: filter, firewall, iptables

I am trying to block external networks from initiating a connection to my internal networks  for both TCP and UDP. My thought is to use --state. I am uncertain about what man page for different states mean.

"NEW meaning that the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions" man page

Does NEW tracks the handshake? As in

client1 -SYN->     client2 NEW
client1 <-SYN,ACK- client2 NEW
client1 -ACK->     client2 ESTABLISHED

-or-

client1 -SYN->     client2 NEW
client1 <-SYN,ACK- client2 NEW
client1 -ACK->     client2 NEW
client1 <-DATA- client2 ESTABLISHED

for UDP

client1 -MSG1->  client2 NEW
client1 <-MSG2-  client2 NEW
client1 -MSG3->  client2 ESTABLISHED

-or-

client1 -MSG1->  client2 NEW
client1 <-MSG2-  client2 ESTABLISHED

Would this block incoming new connection but let new outgoing connection through?

```
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW ! -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED ! -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested UDP but for TCP as soon as the SYN packet was sent the connection become ESTABLISHED so

client1 -SYN-> client2 NEW
client1 <-SYN-ACK- client2 ESTABLISHED

Answer (score 0):

```
client1 -SYN-> client2 NEW
client1 <-SYN,ACK- client2 ESTABLISH
client1 -ACK-> client2 ESTABLISHED
```

Be careful when SYN,ACK, it's should be ESTABLISHED status, if it's SYN,ACK and it's a new connection, it's normally an attack.

and you should add RELATED state too.

well, if you current machine has the ip of 192.168.1.0/24, it will be blocked when creating outgoing connections

My suggest is like this:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A allowed -p TCP -s 192.168.1.0/24 --syn -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A allowed -p TCP -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A allowed -p TCP -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```